# Why is nutritionally complete food always powdered, and are there non powdered versions?

Tags: nutrition

There have been a large number of startups that offer nutritionally complete food, like Soylent and Huel. All of them, as far as I know, offer it mainly in powdered form. You have to mix it with water, and shake it, giving you a 'nutrient drink'.

However, all this mixing is very annoying to me.

**Why do they offer powdered versions only, instead of the kind of bars that astronauts eat?**

Huel offers [this bar version](https://huel.com/products/huel-bar), but its small, and only intended as a side snack.

**Are there any other companies that offer nutrtionally complete food in hard-form rather than powdered-form, that can be used as a primary meal replacement?**

Comment: Probably because making it into a solid form means making it palatable, and that's 1000 times harder than making a powder you mix with other stuff.

Comment: @CareyGregory I'd bet all my money in your theory *(notice the would though, I'm not gonna risk it :P)*

Comment: "A nutritionally complete product that isn't powder." You could try *food*